# how to send data from one python script file to another in pygtk

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to send data from one py file (`stuff.py`) to another py file (`start.py`) in pygtk means I want to send data from one window to another window which I will select in 1st. so anybody let me know how to send data from one file to another file.

I am using `subprocess`.

```
subprocess.call('start.py', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you really should be talking about sending data from one PROCESS to another PROCESS—sending data between files doesn't make much sense (unless you're talking about taking content from file1 and copy-pasting it to file2, but that's clearly not what this is about).

This is called IPC (Inter-Processes Communication). There are various ways how to do that; to list a few options:

- one process writes to a file and the other reads from that file
- one process writes to a named pipe and the other reads from that named pipe (really almost interchangeable with the first option)
- one process connects to the other over TCP/sockets on a port which the other process listens, and they then begin exchanging TCP packets over a period of time
- the processes share part of the RAM of the computer, so that they can write and read from the same place (this can have very good performance, but I'm afraid it's not that simple on Python due to copy-on-write, which gets triggered super easily, AFAIK)
- you use a more high-level IPC mechanism such as ZeroMQ, which are also suitable for networking more generally speaking; these take the burden of handling all the low level technical and protocol details off of your shoulders, so if IPC is something you need to handle on a regular bases and in non-trivial tasks, I strongly suggest you look into ZeroMQ or something similar; see http://zeromq.org and http://zeromq.github.io/pyzmq/ for more information on how to get started, should this be the choice for you.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication.

As to your question about `subprocess.call(...)`—no, this will just invoke the other file creating a completely new process; this will in no way affect any existing processes, regardless of whether they are spawned from `start.py` or not. Also, to my best knowledge, whether your app uses pygtk or not, should be more or less irrelevant to the question of how to do IPC.